# Google Drive APIs: Watch api is giving delayed response

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the [Google Drive Watch APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch), to subscribe on changes. However, the change events I am receiving are really delayed.

It has been observed that the events are sometimes **a day late.**
My expectation would be that *I should get the notifications in near real time.*

Has anybody used it to get google-drive change notifications in real time?